# Setters for collection type properties

Tags: c#, oop, collections

Are setters necessary for Collection Type Properties

```
//Type 1    
class Company
{
    private IList<Customer> customers;

    public IList<Customer> Customers
    {
        get { return customers; }
        set { customers = value; }
    }
}

 //Type 2 
 class Company
 {
       private readonly IList<Customer> customers = new List<Customer>();

       public IList<Customer> Customers
       {
               get { return customers; }
       }
  }
```

When do I use Type 1 vs Type 2 ? 
Wouldn't it suffice if I initialize a List & use readonly property Customers ? as in `Company.Customers.Add(new Customer)`

What is the best practice with respect to providing setters for collection Type properties?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Please read the FxCop recommondation CAS2227 "Collection properties should be read only"
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms182327(VS.80).aspx

it contains good advice :)

Answer (score 2):

Not in general (and I don't normally add them), but they are necessary if you want to use `XmlSerializer`. Which is a pain. It must also be a concrete type (for example `List<T>` or `T[]` - not `IList<T>`). Fortunately, `DataContractSerializer` doesn't suffer the same fate.

Comment: I'd love to know why this got downvoted... fact: XmlSerializer demands setters on collection properties. This isn't opinion, etc - try it...

Answer (score 0):

I prefer

```
public IList<Customer> Customers { get; private set; }
```

But this requries

```
this.Customers = new List<Customer>();
```

in `Company` constructor